# Is there a way to utilize the Push API in Angular without displaying notifications?

Tags: angular, push, push-api

I'm hoping to utilize the [Push API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Push_API) to push data changes from the server to an Angular app, thus removing the need to constantly poll for changes.  Is this possible?  All I can find is [SwPush](https://angular.io/api/service-worker/SwPush) which seems to only allow for pushing of user notifications.  What I need is more about silently updating UI based on changes to back end data.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have control over your API, you could implement [Socket.IO](https://socket.io/)

Are you using a State Management System (i.e. store), such as [NgRx](https://ngrx.io/) or [NGXS](https://www.ngxs.io/)? This way, when you send an API request you can update the store with the response. Essentially giving you that 'live' feeling where the user would not have to reload the page to see the changes.

Comment: Socket.IO may well work, but I was hoping to utilize the Push API.